# Invoke Jquery from Angular2 Component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-components

What is the preferred way to invoke a Jquery function on a DOM element from an Angular2 component?  I need to open a Bootstrap Modal window from a component function.  I have this in my template:

```
<div #httpErrorModal id="errorModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button (click)="hideHttpErrorModal()" type="button" class="close close-button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2>Opps, There Was An Error</h2>
                <!--</div>-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div *ngIf="showErrorModal" class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <div>
                                <p>Sorry there was an error while processing your request.</p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><b>Url: </b>{{httpError.url}}</li>
                                    <li><b>Status Code: </b>{{httpError.statusCode}}</li>
                                    <li><b>Message: </b>{{httpError.message}}</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="evisit btn btn-primary" (click)="hideHttpErrorModal()">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I'm opening the modal from the showHttpErrorModal() below.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private httpError: HttpError;
    private httpErrorObs: any;
    private showErrorModal: boolean = false;

    @ViewChild('httpErrorModal') httpErrorBsModal: ElementRef;

    //temp work around for IE back button issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7873
    constructor(private _applicationRef: ApplicationRef, private _router: Router,
        private _patientService: PatientService, private _configService: ConfigManagerService,
        private _httpErrorService: HttpErrorService) {

        _router.events.subscribe(() => {
            this._applicationRef.tick();
            setTimeout(() => {
                this._applicationRef.tick();
            }, 100);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        //subscribe to error service to handle http error events from main app component
        this.httpErrorObs = this._httpErrorService.errorSubject.subscribe(er => {
            // the observable has an empty object when it is first initialized, so dont do anything if there isn't a status code on the error obj
            if (er.statusCode) {
                this.onHttpError(er);
            }
        });
    }

    onHttpError(hError: HttpError) {
        console.log('in error observable delegate');
        this.httpError = hError;
        this.showErrorModal = true;
        this.showHttpErrorModal();
    }

    showHttpErrorModal() {
        window['jQuery'](this.httpErrorBsModal.nativeElement).modal('show');
    }

    hideHttpErrorModal() {
        window['jQuery'](this.httpErrorBsModal.nativeElement).modal('hide');
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.httpErrorObs.unsubscribe();
        this.showErrorModal = false;
        this.hideHttpErrorModal();
    }

}
```

It's working fine but seems like this goes against the angular way of doing things...  Is there a better approach?

Comment: Could you please explain how it goes against the Angular way of doing things? Because I use a similar approach with a different library. Except that I don't use window, instead I use "declare" for the variable

Comment: I'm pretty new to angular, so I didn't mean to offend.  My apprehension is with

 window['jQuery'](this.httpErrorBsModal.nativeElement).modal('show');

usually i try to have angular handle DOM events and data binding, it just feels like this is circumventing angular's event model, by invoking functions on elements directly.  Also I didn't know if window['jQuery'] was an appropriate way of calling into jquery from angular.

It just feels dirty...

Comment: Hello, don't worry I'm not offended :)
Now it does seem dirty, but I don't see another solution since the modal that you want to show is jquery-based (you could use angular2-modal library if you want angular2 modals), regarding the event loop and databinding and all, angular2 will know of everything you do and will update accordingly, because it monkey-patches all asynchronous events on the browser, so whatever you do, the big brother (angular2) is watching.
I do recommend using angular2-modal though to get modals that work much better in the angular2 realm